# jQuery UI Slider current value customization

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I am playing with this example of the jQuery UI Slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/rangemin.html

I'd like the current/orange value to move along (change his position in parallel) with the slider button and to have values like 10.000 instead of 10000 :) It is possible? I'll show you what I got until now.

http://jsfiddle.net/f3t98/

Any ideas?

Comment: the movement of the value i solved, i'll put inside the class ui-slider-handle link because this is moving and will have absolute position :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the movement of the current value by inserting the input inside the slider link.